# Problems that result from extening singleton class

Tags: singleton

Can anyone explain why we can't extend a singleton class. Precisely, what are the problems that I might face when I try to extend such class.

Answer (score 1):

By extending a singleton class you're breaking the contract of it being a singleton (because the extending class will be able to create another instance that will have the same capabilities as the parent).

Answer (score 0):

By 'extend' do you mean inherit?

A class implementing the singleton design pattern has to have all constructors private.

If you try to inherit, you will not be able to invoke the base class's constructor.